# how do you know when there is no antiderivative written in elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, integration, elementary-functions, differential-algebra

I know that there are integrals that cannot be written in this way such as $e^{-x^2}$ but there is a general rule that can be used to recognize these types of integrals?

Comment: There is a way, but often not easy to do by hand. A key ingredient is [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra))

Comment: No. The only way I know of is to check the integral on WA or search the many lists on Wikipedia. The rest comes with experience.

Comment: @NDB This looks as if it resulted in a power series. But how do we know whether the power series belongs to a known function or not?

Comment: @MariusS.L. Nothing to do with power series. The answer "No" is [mathematically incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), if the coefficients are not too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Theorem:** Given $f, g \in C(X)$ with $f \neq 0$ and $g \neq const$. $f(x)e^{
> g(x)}$
> can be integrated in elementary functions $\iff \exists R ∈ C(X)$ such that
> $$ R'(X) + g'(X)R(X) = f(X)$$ has a solution in $C(X)$.

$C(X)$ is essentially a field of rational functions.

There is a whole theory behind this, so the proof cannot be given in a single post here. If you want to delve deeper, you need a strong abstract algebra background, **differential algebra** specifically. Look into Liouville's theorem in particular.